# Error While deleting Path Range Index

Tags: indexing, marklogic, marklogic-8

I am getting below exception when trying to delete a non-string path range index:-

> ADMIN-NOSUCHITEM: (err:FOER0000) Range Index does not exist.

But I can see that index in database.

I have used delete-range-path-index query to delete the index. This is happening for non- string index.

Below Query is used to delete the Path range index:-

```
import module namespace admin = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/admin"
      at "/MarkLogic/admin.xqy";
let $database := xdmp:database("test")
let $admin-config := admin:get-configuration()
for $index in admin:database-get-range-path-indexes($admin-config, $database)
return admin:database-delete-range-path-index($admin-config, $database, $index)
```

Yes, I used xdmp:set() function to update the admin config so that subsequent calls can use the updated config. But still getting the same error and this is happening when it tries to delete non-string index. When I tried deleting only single non-string index, I got the same Exception.

We are using marklogic version:- 8.0-5.9

Comment: How are you deleting it?

Comment: I have used the delete-range-path-index query to delete the index.this is happening for non-string index.

Comment: Could you edit your question, and append the code that you are using to create and delete the index? It could be something small like forgetting to spell out the type to look for, but hard to tell without code.

Comment: Hi @grtjn, please help me out in resolving this error.

Comment: Are you also saving the config changes using `admin:save-configuration()`? Note that each call to `admin:database-delete-range-path-index()` returns an updated version of $admin-config. You will need to use `xdmp:set()`, or a recursive function to make sure each subsequent call uses the updated config. Or, you could just delete all indexes at once since `admin:database-delete-range-path-index()` can take a sequence too..

Comment: It could also be useful to know what version of MarkLogic you are using exactly..

Comment: Hi @grtjn, i have updated the question with details. Please help.

Comment: To be honest, you might be better off reaching out to MarkLogic Support, if you or your company is entitled to it..

Answer (score 0):

I took the effort of spinning up a Vagrant vm with CentOS 7.4 (using https://github.com/grtjn/mlvagrant), and MarkLogic 8.0-5.9 as you specified (for RH7 though), but am unable to reproduce your issue. I ran the following, which returned without errors:

```
import module namespace admin = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/admin"
      at "/MarkLogic/admin.xqy";

let $database := xdmp:database()
let $admin-config := admin:get-configuration()
let $admin-config := admin:database-add-range-path-index(
  $admin-config,
  $database,
  admin:database-range-path-index(
    $database,
    "int",
    "/x" || xdmp:random(),
    "http://marklogic.com/collation/",
    fn:false(),
    "reject"
  )
)
return
  admin:save-configuration-without-restart($admin-config)

;

import module namespace admin = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/admin"
      at "/MarkLogic/admin.xqy";

let $database := xdmp:database()
let $admin-config := admin:get-configuration()
let $admin-config := admin:database-delete-range-path-index(
  $admin-config,
  $database,
  admin:database-get-range-path-indexes($admin-config, $database)
)
return
  admin:save-configuration-without-restart($admin-config)
;

import module namespace admin = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/admin"
      at "/MarkLogic/admin.xqy";

let $database := xdmp:database()
let $admin-config := admin:get-configuration()
return
  admin:database-get-range-path-indexes($admin-config, $database)
```

Can you elaborate on how you created that range path index?

HTH!

Comment: @rajat-jain, please edit your question to add more details, and leave a brief comment below here to notify me..